# pip not working after installing another python version

Tags: centos, python, pip

My CentOS 6.5 machine already had Python 2.6 installed in it. Now I just installed Python 2.7. But now, pip is not working. Whenever I run any pip command, it shows following error-

```
File "/usr/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 92
    _blocking_errnos = {errno.EAGAIN, errno.EWOULDBLOCK}
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am not understanding what the actual problem is.

Comment: Which `pip` are you using? You need to specify the version, ie. `pip3.7`. Also, why are you using 2.6? Or even 2.7?

Comment: Funny thing: even running `pip --version` command returns same error. And I know it's embarrassing  to use older Python versions, but you know I have to, and it's not in my hands :D

Comment: `which pip` should tell you what it's trying to do. It appears to me that it's attempting to run `2.7` using `2.6` code. Also check your aliases. On top of that, my recommendation is to move away from 2.6.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue on a CentOS 6 machine. For me an reinstall worked:

```bsh
sudo yum remove python-pip
sudo yum install python-pip
```

then I was able to verify that it work via:

```bsh
python --version
Python 2.6.6

pip --version
pip 7.1.0 from /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages (python 2.6)
```